With itextsharp how to include a link on the PDF?
I can't seem to find an answer to how to include a link when using iTextSharp.  Here's just some normal lines in the PDF:
            PdfPTable pdftable4 = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdftable4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tax and shipping calculated at time of shipment. If shipping is quoted, rates are subject to change based on time of shipment. Quote is valid for 30 days.", pdffont_h));
            cell2.Colspan = 10;
            cell2.DisableBorderSide(2);
            pdftable4.AddCell(cell2);

            PdfPTable pdftable5 = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdftable5.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Unless explicitly stated in quote description, manufacturing quality and accuracy is based on the expectations defined in ", pdffont_h));
            cell5.Colspan = 10;
            cell5.DisableBorderSide(2);
            pdftable5.AddCell(cell5);

But now I'm trying to add a HTML Link: I've tried a few things:
            var c = new Chunk("Fathommfg");
            c.SetAnchor("https://www.google.com");
            PdfPTable pdftable6 = new PdfTable(1);
            PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("https://www.google.com"));
            cell6.AddElement(c);
            pdftable6.AddCell(cell6);

            document.Add(pdftable6);

This 'SetAnchor' code doesn't seem to work.  How to do this correctly?  In my googling, I've seen a few examples using different types of iText, but the help isn't using the same APIs or code I'm currently using. This is iTextSharp by Bruno Lowagie.

The link does work, thank you.  However, I'm having trouble making it 'blue' or 'underline'.   Must be simple formatting commands.

You need to just use:
            PdfPTable pdftable6 = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdftable6.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("https://www.google.com");
            p.Font.Color = BaseColor.BLUE;
            PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(p);
            cell6.Colspan = 10;
            cell6.DisableBorderSide(2);
            pdftable6.AddCell(cell6);

The PDF will automatically recognize the URL as a link.  As I've done above I also artificially colored it 'Blue'.
